# Mail download save in sql server

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know of a script to download email from Gmail and store it to a SQL server? (for backup purposes)

I am looking for a .NET solution (C#).

Comment: I was able to download the mail from gmail server..which creates a .eml file..i am not able to store it in database..cn u help me with that??

Comment: i am not able to post the code...can anyone help me with the above required code

Comment: This post should not have been closed. Although not an awfully high quality question it is a valid one and appears to have been answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EML files are plain text.

Simply create a table in your database with one column (and all the others you need, that's for you to decide) of type nvarchar(max) that will store the contents of the email file. For example call this column `email_content`

Then do something like this:

```
string email = File.ReadAllText("Path/to/EML/File");
```

And then do something like:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionStringHere"))
{

   con.Open();
   using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO your_table (email_content) values (@email_content)",con)
   {

       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email_content",email);
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

*That's assuming you are using SQL Server but the principle is the same for any other database.

Comment: yeah thnx lcarus...and also thnx to Maxim..